# Authentication in windows app "Cannot work with a MobileServiceClient that does not specify a gateway URI."

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, win-universal-app

I am trying to implement user authentication in my universal app (without using Mobile Services) as given in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users-preview/) article. However I am getting following error:

> Cannot work with a MobileServiceClient that does not specify a gateway URI.

As I am not using mobile service for auth and doing it in client universal app, I am not sure what url goes here. Currently, "http://MyApp.azurewebsites.net" is the url for the backend app which I have in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com)(Browse All > MyApp > Settings > url).

**In my shared App.xaml.cs:**

```
//Problem may be here as per my understanding
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = 
    new MobileServiceClient("http://MyApp.azurewebsites.net");
```

**In my shared MainPage.cs:**

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task AuthenticateAsync()
{
    string message;

    // This sample uses the Microsoft provider.
    var provider = "MicrosoftAccount";    

    // Use the PasswordVault to securely store and access credentials.
    PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
    PasswordCredential credential = null;    
    while (credential == null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Try to get an existing credential from the vault.
            credential = vault.FindAllByResource(provider).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // When there is no matching resource an error occurs, 
            // which we ignore.
        }    
        if (credential != null)
        {
            // Create a user from the stored credentials.
            user = new MobileServiceUser(credential.UserName);
            credential.RetrievePassword();
            user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = credential.Password;

            // Set the user from the stored credentials.
            App.MobileService.CurrentUser = user;

            try
            {
                // Try to return an item now to determine 
                // if the cached credential has expired.
                await App.MobileService
                    .GetTable<TodoItem>().Take(1).ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Response.StatusCode == 
                        System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    // Remove the credential with the expired token.
                    vault.Remove(credential);
                    credential = null;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Login with the identity provider.
                // Here I am getting the exception.
                user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(provider);

                // Create and store the user credentials.
                credential = new PasswordCredential(provider,
                user.UserId, user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
                vault.Add(credential);
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                message = "You must log in. Login Required";
            }
        }
        message = string.Format("You are now logged in - {0}", user.UserId);
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

So what is **Gateway Uri**, what I am doing wrong and how to implement authentication in app only without Azure Mobile Service (MVC project hosted on azure).

Answer (score 2):

The App needs to have an associated gateway. For further reading, [checkout this article on the Azure website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-migrating-from-mobile-services-preview/). You will want to have code like this:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
  mobileAppUri: "https://mvp2015mobileapp.azurewebsites.net", 
  gatewayUri: "https://mvp2015b14929cfc35019b24a7daaf694.azurewebsites.net",
  applicationKey: string.Empty);
```

## Find an existing App Service gateway

From portal.azure.com, open your Mobile App, and click on its resource group link. Once the resource group blade opens, click on its summary panel. If you already have a Gateway, it will be in the list.

[image: Gateway]

## Create a new App Service gateway

From portal.azure.com, open your Mobile App, choose Settings, and then Mobile User Authentication. You will be able to create a new gateway from there. Here is a screen shot that shows where to create the Gateway (and also shows the Resource Group link.)

[image: Create Gateway]

## Retreive the gateway URL

Once you have found the gateway, you can grab its URL.

[image: Gateway URL]